# output of regular expression in sml

Tags: sml

There's a question for finding all output of length less than 6 in the following expression:
(a+b|ba+)+.
And there are 19 outputs.I can find part of them.

but I don't know why "abba,baab,aabab,abaab,baaab,abbaa,baaba,babaa" are part of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples that should help you figure out the rest:

- abba: `ab` is from the first part (1 or more `a` followed by `b`) and `ba` is from the second part (one b followed by 1 or more `a`s).
- baab: similar
- babaa: `ba` `baa` both from the second part (since you can have one or more of the group due to the final `+`.

Comment: but there are "|" between left and right.It means "or". Why it can be combined together rather than selected one of them?

Comment: also the precedence of () is higher than the rightest "+". It must compute the things in the () then apply "+" to the result